# Deployer Error on 2013 SP1/ TRI - JDBC Driver/Datasource class could not be found, org.hsqldb?

Tags: 2013, content-porter-2013, deployer, dxa

I'm setting up the TRI.  It's gone pretty smooth, but I'm stuck on getting the deployer set up.  I'm getting the error below when I try & publish to it.  The CME, Deployer & Broker DB are all on the same server.  I'm using Sql Server.  Any ideas?

```
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fatal error, unable to load the StorageManagerFactory
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.reloadInstance(StorageManagerFactory.java:88) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.<clinit>(StorageManagerFactory.java:56) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: JDBC Driver/Datasource class could not be found, org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource, org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource
    at com.tridion.storage.util.JDBCDataSourceBeanConfigurer.registerJDBCDataSource(JDBCDataSourceBeanConfigurer.java:65) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.util.JDBCDataSourceBeanConfigurer.configure(JDBCDataSourceBeanConfigurer.java:42) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.util.SpringContextDynamicConfigurer.configureDatasource(SpringContextDynamicConfigurer.java:81) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.util.SpringContextDynamicConfigurer.configureDatasource(SpringContextDynamicConfigurer.java:55) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.session.SessionWrapperFactory.configure(SessionWrapperFactory.java:78) ~[cd_session.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageWrapperLoader.configure(StorageWrapperLoader.java:30) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.configuration.step.ConfigurationStepLoader.configure(ConfigurationStepLoader.java:47) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.configure(StorageManagerFactory.java:137) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.services.BaseService.<init>(BaseService.java:107) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.<init>(StorageManagerFactory.java:104) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.reloadInstance(StorageManagerFactory.java:84) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
```

Comment: You may be missing JDBC jar - please refer to the following SDL documentation link: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-19D0779D-3AA1-42EA-A684-9E21B33D823B

Comment: The sql server jdbc jar is present.

Comment: do you have a valid cd_licenses.xml? Is cd_storage_conf.xml configured correctly? Does incoming folder have correct read/write permission?

Comment: thanks for the replies. The issue was a mis-configured cd_storage.conf file

Answer (score 2):

This definitely looks like you're missing the file jdbc4.jar:

> com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: JDBC
>   Driver/Datasource class could not be found,
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource

You'll need to download this file from [Microsoft's website](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774) and place it within the /bin/lib folder of your deployer.